# Making duplicate Entries in php my admin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to make a table in php my admin where I can add in duplicate data into a column so I'd have Event ID and Band ID column and it'd be like (1,3), (1,5) (2,4)
So I can have more than one band relate to one event. 
My two tables look like this:

[image]

[image]

Band_ID and Event_ID should be a composite primary key in the second table. How do I do this in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to use the same `Event_ID` values for multiple rows in your second table? Are you sure that the column is not defined as being `UNIQUE`?

Comment: We need to see the content of the INSERT you are trying to write. Also, it would help if you exported the CREATE statements for both tables rather than just showing screenshots. (In PMA, go to EXPORT and click through to export the table structure as SQL.) Finally, it would help if you could clarify that you're adding the records to the Events table first before you attempt to add them to the Event_bands table. Need a lot more information here.

Comment: This is the events table: http://gyazo.com/be159740ae7502b29e305544bcb058b0.png
This is the eventbandlink table: 
http://gyazo.com/331af82f86ff6681d9366e5214467d3a.png
I already have all the data I need in the Events and Bands table and I am just using that.
The Insert query I am using is:
http://gyazo.com/17f820323e62dfbe74f2d29e66e05eaa.png
and this is the error message I get:
http://gyazo.com/20312e1324780cc279945a10dd5c86bb.png

Comment: `Event ID` and `Band ID` are both defined as `UNIQUE`. You should drop both of those indices. The only unique one you want is the event-band. `Event ID` also should not be the primary key in that case. Add another column, say `Link ID`, and make that the primary key with an auto-increment.

Comment: So should Event ID be the only unique column?

Comment: No. Neither Event ID nor Band ID alone should be unique, only the combination of the two.

Comment: Okay I have the table, how do I make both Event ID and Band ID a unique key combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your question to reflect your clarifications shown above. The new question is "how do I create a composite key in PhpMyAdmin?" (A composite key is when two columns make up a primary key. You asked "how do I make both Event ID and Band ID a unique key combination?")

To do this in PhpMyAdmin, go into the structure of the table, and select both columns at once. Then click the "key" icon below it, as shown:
[image]

Comment: that still gives me an error when i add duplicate data in

Comment: okay actually, sorry for this but it worked with my own values but then when i linked they to other tables with the 'relation viewer' i get an error again.